# Vue watch[fat arrow scope] providing wrong this context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using lodash to debounce a function call but I am wondering why my `this` value is not inheriting the scope like I expect.

These are are the relevant parts of my Vue component.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

watch: {
    query: debounce(() => {
        this.autocomplete();
    }, 200, {
        leading: false,
        trailing: true
    }),
```

The above case does not work because my `this` value does not point to the Vue component but rather shows an Object like this:

```
Object
    __esModule: true
    default: Object
    __proto: Object
```

Isn't my arrow syntax suppose to inherit the context of `this`?

The following seem to works fine:

```
query: debounce(function test() {
    this.autocomplete();
}, 200, {
    leading: false,
    trailing: true
})
```

There is probably an easy answer for this but I am hoping someone can help me out here.

Comment: Use regular functions instead of arrow functions if you need Vue `this` context. You can find it throughout Vue's documentation.

Comment: You should probably read up on how arrow functions work. E.g. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: @nils They work exactly as I expect them to work, just not with Vue apparently. The answer below explains more.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to point to. It's easy to make wrong assumptions about the current scope of arrow functions (this has nothing to do with vue).

Comment: @nils Care to explain why the parent context is not what I expect it to be than? There are probably a lot of people who fall for this, since they have taken it into the official documentation. Might help some people.

Comment: What about this though? https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/3792/changing-to-es2015-using-arrows-i-got-an-error-for-this/5 It seems because Vue binds these properties, methods and events by default that is why the context is different.

Comment: I'll post a separate answer about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only an additional answer to explain the misunderstanding of `this` in arrow functions.

**How does this work in arrow functions?**

`this` in lexical functions always refers to the surrounding scope. That can either be:

1. The nearest surrounding function
2. The nearest surrounding module
3. The global scope

If we have a look at your code, and we assume you're using ES6 modules (judging from the `import/export` statements):

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default {
    watch: {
        query: debounce(() => {
            this.autocomplete();
        }, 200, {
            leading: false,
            trailing: true
        }),
    }
};
```

Let's go through the list:

**1. The nearest surrounding function**

There is no surrounding function for your arrow function. An example would be:

```
var obj = {
    a: function() {
        return () => {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
};

obj.a()(); // `this` refers to `obj`, because `this` refers to `obj` in the surrounding function `a`
```

**2. The nearest surrounding module**

Since we are in a (fake) module in this case, `this` is defined in the module scope as pseudo module object (probably a babel or webpack object?).

```
Object
    __esModule: true
    default: Object
    __proto: Object
```

**It seems because Vue binds these properties, methods and events by default**

That's true and it's a very useful feature of vue. But it doesn't help us in this case, because *`this` cannot be overridden in an arrow function, it always refers to the surrounding scope*.

Have a look at the following link for a deeper understanding of arrow functions: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#_variables-that-are-lexical-in-arrow-functions

Comment: Thanks, but I think str's answer is more on point as it actually solves your problem. I only provide context.

Answer (score 7):

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback (e.g. `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod()))`. As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be undefined.

As the same limitation applies to watchers, you have to use something like this:

```
watch: {
    query: function() {
        return debounce(() => {
            this.autocomplete();
        },
        200,
        {
            leading: false,
            trailing: true
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: I should read more documentation. Thanks man, this is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: extra reference https://gist.github.com/JacobBennett/7b32b4914311c0ac0f28a1fdc411b9a7